# MVC3 / EF - Changing model... Database schema mismatch

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have been following the [ASP.Net Movie Database Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/movie-database/create-a-movie-database-application-in-15-minutes-with-asp-net-mvc-cs), and it was all going well.

I have just changed the model and added an attribute. Call me curious, but I didn't want to follow the guide of just drop the database - I wanted to see if I can modify.

The [correct error](http://aspnet13.orcsweb.com/media/866051/WindowsLiveWriter_ImplementingEditDetailsandDelete_11047_BackingError_thumb_1.png) came up about a mismatch - which was expected.

I added the ratings column to the database, and everything worked.

Next, I deleted the ratings column as I wanted to follow the tutorial and learn about `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` - however, I just get the error `Invalid column name 'Ratings'.`

In all this time, the `ModelHash` entry has not changed, and I have no idea how it know there is a difference between now or before.

So - 1) Have I screwed something up?

2) How can I fix?

3) How did it know before that something has changed, but not now when the hash hasn't changed?

4) Is there any additional advice you can give?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you description must be incorrect because correct behavior will throw the exception despite of manually added `Rating` column.

This behavior works as follows:

1. When database is created new table called `EdmMetadata` is added.
2. `EdmMetadata` contains two columns - `Id` and `ModelHash`.
3. Part of database creation is storing single row with hash of the current model.
4. If database was not created by the current context the context executes a query to retrieve stored model hash before the first operation is executed. The retrieved has is compared with context's current hash.
5. If hash is not the same and database recreation is not allowed by database initializer the exception is thrown.
6. If hash is the same, required db operation is executed.

Adding manually `Rating` column will not change stored hash but hash of the model will be different.

This behavior can be completely removed by removing `IncludeMetadataConvention` convention:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove(modelBuilder.Conventions
            .OfType<IncludeMetadataConvention>().ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm - I can ensure you that what I said is exactly what I did... I followed that guide fine - modified the model which came up with an exception, then instead of dropping/writing the script they suggested, I added the column and it just worked fine.

Comment: @Wil: Interesting. I just did the same in console application and manually adding the column to the table didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Going over some of my old questions... Again, I can ensure you on the sequence of events, but, you know a heck of a lot more than me on this... There must of been something else going on. Marking as answer and may unmark in the future if I have time/can reproduce again. +1 thanks